# Unused var in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React Hooks in my SPA. I know how it works, but I have a doubt when declaring the hook, i.e., I'm using `react-cookie` and the declaration of the hook is `const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies([]);`.

In my case, I will only need the `removeCookie` `var`, I won't use the `cookies` and `setCookie` `vars` in my functional page, so `lint` complains about unused vars.

Is it possible to ignore these two `vars`? I tried `const [..., ..., removeCookie] = useCookies([]);` but this won't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you use array destructuring to make the assignments, you can [ignore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) the items by adding commas without the variables/consts names:

```
const [,, removeCookie] = useCookies([]);
```

Example:

```js
const [,, c] = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(c)
```